# Problem with zeki tablet: no space

Tags: internal-storage

Ok, so my tablet is a 4 gig and has no space. I factory reset it because it had some major problems. Anyways, when I go into the settings I go into the apps part and it says 147mb free yet I have nothing installed or downloaded so I don't know what to do. It's stupid and pissing me off. I've tried alot of things. I've taken all the updates out of the apps and still no space. Please give me some direction. Is there a program to root, because if so I need it bad because this tablet sucks.

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage). You may have to delete an app or an app's data  to get some space for the said apps' installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your apps off tablet drive and put them on the internal sd card. 
Go to settings-Apps. Slide the screen to "on sd card" (upper right of screen). Check box the apps to move. Then go back to "downloaded" screen. Click each app and clear data, clear cache.
That freed up 100mb on mine. Good luck

Comment: I downloaded an app to move apps from the internal storage to the SD card and the message I received was "the internal storage and the sd card SHARE the same space" so apps CANNOT be moved from the internal storage to the sd storage.